# Seldom used system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am doing some experiments, and need a seldom used Linux syscall for performance testing of hooking a function for some instrumentation.

I need a pair of the syscall and one simple function on its execution path.

The syscall is better not used by other applications, and the kernel part is simple enough.
Also, it is better that one system call can be mapped to a simple kernel function (one-to-one mapping).

Previously I found pair (futex syscall/do_futex, futex_requeue) is a good candidate, but in the kernel it sometimes triggers more than 1 function call. And when I run more than 10000 times, the system sometimes crashes.

Any recommendation?

Comment: I guess one of the obsolete syscall numbers would do, but most of those aren't implemented on newer architectures such as x86_64. For i386, possible syscall numbers to consider would be 18 (oldstat), 84 (oldlstat), 59 (oldolduname), or 109 (olduname), but x86_64 has no native equivalents of those, although it will support them when running 32-bit, x86 stuff in compatibility mode. For native x86_64, you could possibly use 214 (epoll_ctl_old), or 215 (epoll_wait_old).

Comment: Great suggestion! How about (32-bit) ARM?

Comment: For ARM, look in `arch/arm/kernel/calls.S` for the ones that map to `sys_ni_syscall` or the ones that use the `OBSOLETE(syscall)` macro. The `OBSOLETE(syscall)` macro is defined in `arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S` and will expand to `sys_ni_syscall` if the `CONFIG_AEABI` is defined, or will expand to its parameter as-is if `CONFIG_AEABI` is not defined.